# How can I create a trigger in phpmyadmin, that after insert will update a field in anther table?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table called `userlikes` that has columns `give_like_id`, `receive_like_id`.

I also have a `users` table with `count_likes` and `id` columns. Every time a new record is inserted into `userlikes` table, I want to decrease by -1 in `countlikes` table.

- `userlikes`: give_like_id, receive_like_id
- `users`: id, count_likes

I tried this code, but it's not working.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_count_likes` 
AFTER INSERT 
ON `user_likes` 
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE users 
    SET users.likes_count = users.likes_count - 1
    WHERE users.id = user_likes.give_like_id
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MySQL?)

Comment: hey , i am using mysql

Comment: Before giving yourself a headache to maintain such a count via triggers, ask yourself if you actually need it. It's *derived* data - you can always calculate it by aggregating on the userlikes table. When you *store* derived data, you introduce the opportunity for *inconsistency*, where the stored count and the number of rows in the table are different (for some as yet undiscovered reason)

Answer (score 0):

> hey, the answer for it:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `update_count_likes` AFTER INSERT ON `user_likes`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE users 
SET users.likes_count
= users.likes_count -1
WHERE users.id=NEW.give_like_id
```

Comment: Can you explain what is different between your answer and the code at the end of his question ? Please edit your answer :)

Comment: There is no big diffrence i add the NEW , and i had a mistakes, with coulmes names, the code logics was correct even in the question.